# and loading NIB / XIB files?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am a little curious, I have a view controller class and an NIB/XIB (both are named "MapViewController") If I do the following it loads the NIB with the matching name.

```
-(id)init {
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"MapViewController" bundle:nil];
    if(self) {
        do things ...
    }
    return self;
}
```

if on the other hand I just specify [super init] does Xcode just look for a NIB that matches the name of the controller, is that how this is working?

```
-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        do things ...
    }
    return self;
}
```

cheers Gary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the documentation:

> If you specify nil for the nibName
>   parameter and do not override the
>   loadView method in your custom
>   subclass, the default view controller
>   behavior is to look for a nib file
>   whose name (without the .nib
>   extension) matches the name of your
>   view controller class. If it finds
>   one, the class name becomes the value
>   of the nibName property, which results
>   in the corresponding nib file being
>   associated with this view controller.

Comment: Thank you, I see it now, I was looking under init and getting lost.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in this particular case it will work. According to the [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), calling `init` is similar to calling `initWithNibName:bundle:` with `nil` as nib name:

> If you specify nil for the nibName
>   parameter and do not override the
>   loadView method in your custom
>   subclass, the default view controller
>   behavior is to look for a nib file
>   whose name (without the .nib
>   extension) matches the name of your
>   view controller class. If it finds
>   one, the class name becomes the value
>   of the nibName property, which results
>   in the corresponding nib file being
>   associated with this view controller.

Answer (score 1):

> does Xcode just look for a NIB that
>   matches the name of the controller

Pretty much:

> If you specify nil for the nibName
>   parameter and do not override the
>   loadView method in your custom
>   subclass, the default view controller
>   behavior is to look for a nib file
>   whose name (without the .nib
>   extension) matches the name of your
>   view controller class. If it finds
>   one, the class name becomes the value
>   of the nibName property, which results
>   in the corresponding nib file being
>   associated with this view controller.